# My mysql databases crash with high traffic

Tags: php, mysql, database, crash, high-traffic

I have a Travian Private server (its a browser based online game) and after I install the script on my site it works perfectly, but just when the online users pass a certain amount (like 20 online user) I start getting a mysql errors.
this one : Warning: mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQL.php on line 2750

and after I get this error message, I start getting more errors for parts that was working perfectly before (like header errors for example)

so basically when I get this error from that point the game goes to crapper slowly..
I even tried repairing the DB but that just makes more problems since it effects the game and ruins it. (I still tried it couple of times and didn't fix the problem)

can anyone help me with this? 
how can I prevent the database from crashing due to high tarffic?

Comment: See your process list via `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`. See last error via `mysql_error()` (and, in fact, don't use **mysql_** - they are deprecated). Profile & debug your application - that's all I can suggest you since have no data about the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, 
I have to use mysql_ since the script of the game was designed to work with that.
but I'll give that profile & debug a shot.